# Load Balancer "A Record" entry does not work in GoDaddy's A Record field

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I had a question about using the URL in my Load Balancer - and using it as the A Record for my DNS entry via GoDaddy...GoDaddy doesn't allow a URL, and insists on the A Record being an IP address and no other format. But I don't see this option available in the Load Balancer I created, only a URL.

What I have so far is this..

I've created a Load Balancer successfully using both HTTP and HTTPS, along with the RapidSSL cert I purchased and imported.

When I open my new Load Balancer item in EC2 dashboard, under the Description tab, I see an auto-generated URL next to DNS Name: http://ACThttp-617756314.us-east-2.elb.amazonaws.com (A record)

The above URL works fine in my browser. I went to plug this into GoDaddy'a A record in the DNS settings --- but apparently GoDaddy only allows an IP address to be used as an A Record...and not a URL like the one generated by EC2. I find this confusing since it literally says "A Record" next to this generated URL in my Load Balancer.

Does this mean I need to generate an IP Address inEC2 dashboard, so that I can use it in GoDaddy DNS settings? I'm guessing this is done via Route53...or could I skip this altogether and still find a way to connect my new Load Balancer to my DNS A record some other way?

However this is done, any help would be appreciated. If Route53, what are the exact steps I need to take? Or any other solutions, as much detail you could provide would be so so so helpful.

I've done this a few times successfully in the past, but it was a while ago and I can't recall how I connected them to the DNS properly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a `CNAME` record (*not* an `A` record).

A [CNAME record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNAME_record) points to another DNS name, whereas an `A` record points to an IP address.

Load Balancers should always be addressed by their DNS Name, so use a `CNAME` record.

Answer (score 0):

Delete the old cname or A records from godaddy, then only be the new records added

Comment: What do you mean by _'then only be the new records added'_?